# Remove/Delete GridView HeaderRow when exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, html, excel, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a task in my project to export GridView data to Excel file, what I would like to do is to remove the header row from exported excel file (first-row shown in excel file)
my code is here:

```
  public ActionResult ExportFirstTermResultToExcel(string id)
    {
        var gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = this.GetFirstTermResult(id);
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfilenam.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
        foreach (GridViewRow Gr in gv.Rows)
        {

            foreach (TableCell GVtableCell in Gr.Cells)
            {
                GVtableCell.Attributes.Add("style", "textmode");
            }
        }
        gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return View("Index");
    }
```

So please help me if you know how to do that

Regards

Comment: Maybe use a "for" loop instead of "foreach" and start with i = 1

Comment: the "foreach" loop has nothing to do with the header row the index of the first row is 0 . and the header row has no index